# how to use regex to chech if a single character is a special character

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a single character is special in regex.

```
let char = "?";
if(condition){
  console.log("The char is a special character");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know this, or what is your interest in regex metacharacters?

Comment: My code requires it

Comment: What do you consider special, and what do you consider not special? If you just mean not A-Z and not 0-9, just check `[^A-Za-z0-9]` rather than try to put every other character into an expression

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, who knows? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a RegExp \W represents each special character

definition : \W Matches any character that is not a word character from the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to [^A-Za-z0-9_].

You can find a list of those characters here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Character_classes

```js
const format = /\W/g;

const checkFormat = (string) => {
    if(format.test(string)){
      return (`The char "${string}" is a special character`);
    } else {
      return (`The char "${string}" is not a special character`);
    }
}
alert(checkFormat("?"));
alert(checkFormat("n"));
alert(checkFormat("☺️"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const format = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;

const checkFormat = (string) => {
    if(format.test(string)){
      return console.log("The char is a special character");
    } else {
      return console.log("No special character");
    }
}
checkFormat('?');
```

Comment: `checkFormat(☺️)`

Comment: @Popnoodles Thanks for sharing your thought. Really appreciate.
One solution for the this kind of case is to use a emoji format as well, like :


/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/u.test('☺️')

Comment: More can be found out in - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex

Answer (score 0):

```
let char = "?";
let condition = /[^a-zA-Z1-4]/g;

if (condition.test(char)) {
    console.log("The char is a special character");
}
```

Comment: What's with 1 through 4?